# Select All except Parents in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I Have Following codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#ThisClick").anycommand();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="TopUl">
    <li>First<ul>
        <li>One<ul>
            <li>liA1</li>
            <li>liA2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Two<ul>
            <li id="ThisClick">liB1</li>
            <li>liB2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second<ul>
        <li>li1<ul>
            <li>liF1</li>
            <li>liF2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>li2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I need collaps all UL's that are not parents of liB1 (#ThisClick) when clicking.
In other words by click on liB1 I want have following code:

```
<ul id="TopUl">
    <li>First<ul>
        <li>One<ul style="display:none">
            <li>liA1</li>
            <li>liA2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Two<ul>
            <li id="ThisClick">liB1</li>
            <li>liB2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second<ul style="display:none">
        <li>li1<ul style="display:none">
            <li>liF1</li>
            <li>liF2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>li2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then Jquery may collapse all not parented UL tags.
What is the solution? how can I do for this propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icky looking selector should work:

```
$("ul :not(:has(#ThisClick))").hide();
```

References: [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

---

So, this bit of code will make all the elements that are not parents of the element you clicked, hide. Change the first selector (`$("#ThisClick")`) as needed, right now it only works on the `<li>` that you've specified the `ThisClick` ID on, and you can only use an ID once.

```
$("#ThisClick").click(function() {
    $("ul :not(:has(this))").hide();
});
```

To make this work on *all* `<li>`s that are in your `<ul>`, you could do this:

```
$("#TopUl li").click(function() {
    $("ul :not(:has(this))").hide();
});
```

This adds the click event to all `<li>`s in your list.

Comment: @Elliot_Bonneville that is great solution, but I need it without ID specification. Other word my clicked li may have not any ID.

Comment: In that case just replace `#ThisClick` with `this` in your click handler. Inside your click handler `this` will refer to the object clicked.

Comment: You are very expert in jquery, but I am newbe in it. So I couldn't undrstand it. Can you show it clearly? Do you means : `$("ul :not(:has(this))").hide();`

Comment: @Huseyin: Let me explain in my answer.